# Como fazer uma barra de scroll feita por css no microsoft edge voltar ao topo quando se troca de página?

Tags: css, rolamento, angular-5

- Erro no: Microsoft Edge
- Tecnologia utilizada: Angular(4+)
- Quando acontece: ***Somente quando o tamanho ta tela está pequeno, e não
  é possível exibir todos os itens da listagem da tabela***
- Tabela Utilizada: **Angular Material**

Seguinte, estou fazendo um projeto com Angular(4+), em que estou usando uma tabela do Angular Material.

A nossa **barra de Scroll** é ativada quando a ***tela está pequena***, e quando o usuário clica em ***próximos itens***, o edge renderiza os próximos itens, com a barra de ***scroll setada para baixo***

A primeira vista, o edge exibe a tabela normalmente com a barra de scroll e os itens. Quando o usuário clica para ver os próximos resultados, já que exibimos 10 de cada vez, o edge renderiza com a scroll setada pra baixo, forçando assim o usuário a ter que subir o scroll da tela novamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Scroll é criado através da seguinte **classe css:**

```
  .table-container {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: auto;   
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
```

Código que eu utilizei para resolver:

```
  /** 
   * This function fix report scroll position after change page listener 
   */ 
  materialScrollDownToUp() { 
    document.getElementById('material-scroll-detect').scrollTop = 0; 
  }
```

Depois você só faz usar essa chamada onde precisa, e não fica em um loop, abraços.

Comment: É só Edge que acontece isso?

Comment: @dvd sim, é só no microsoft edge que acontece isso

Comment: @dvd beleza, vou tentar aqui

Comment: @dvd deu certo brother, o lance era o local onde setar o ID saca ? eu estava setando na div pai, porém o local correto era pra ser colocado lá <mat-table> </mat-table>, que onda, mas valeu parceiro pela clareada ai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mova o scroll do elemento para o topo usando `scrollTop = 0` com um pequeno delay no `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector(seletor).scrollTop = 0;
}, 50);
```

Onde tem `seletor` você coloca uma id, classe, tag ou que for preciso para selecionar o elemento em que você deseja aplicar o scroll.

Comment: Essa forma tbem dá certo, só que eu fiz da seguinte maneira @dvd. Coloquei o scrollTop em uma função, nesse caso eu não entro em um loop e fica tranquilo, saca:   /** 
   * This function fix report scroll position after change page listener 
   */ 
  materialScrollDownToUp() { 
    document.getElementById('material-scroll-detect').scrollTop = 0; 
  }

Comment: Saquei. fica legal tb